# Get value of TextBox if 1s elapsed after last change c#

Tags: c#

how can I get the value of my textbox 1seconde after the last change .

I tried with Stopwatch and TimerStamp but I just get the time between two change I don't know how to get the value of textbox 1 seconde after.

Thanks for help!

Edit:

```
   Stopwatch TimerBetweenWrite = new Stopwatch();

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimerBetweenWrite.Stop();
        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = TimerBetweenWrite.Elapsed;

        if (Search.Text != null && ts.Seconds >= 1)
        {
            //doing my stuff
        }
        TimerBetweenWrite.Restart();
   }
```

But this don't work like I want because we need to change the TextBox 1 seconde after last change. I want run a function 1 seconde after the last change of the TextBox but the user can continue to change the TextBox.

**Final Edit:**

That the code which work Thank's all for help!

```
public partial class ViewerPage : Page
{
    System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    public ViewerPage()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);
    }

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        myTimer.Stop(); //Reset timer
        myTimer.Start(); //Restart it
     }

     private void myTimer_Elapsed(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {
         ThreadContext.InvokeOnUiThread(
         delegate()
         {
             // Doing My Stuff 
             myTimer.Stop();
          });
     }
}

public static class ThreadContext
{
    public static void InvokeOnUiThread(Action action)
    {
        if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            action();
         }
         else
         {
             Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
         }
     }

     public static void BeginInvokeOnUiThread(Action action)
     {
         if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
         {
             action();
         }
         else
         {
             Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: show some code! did you use the Timer event? Did you set the interval to be fired every second? on the Timer Tick event, check the value of the textbox. However this seems inefficient to what you may want to be doing. Giving us more details about what you are accomplishing would help us in giving you a better solution to the problem.

Comment: Handle the TextChanged event and have a Timer for the interval of 1 second, and on the callback just handle how you need to handle this event (and then disable the timer).

Comment: i have edit with more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer(1000);
myTimer.Elapsed += myTimer_Elapsed;
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    myTimer.Stop(); //Reset timer
    myTimer.Start(); //Restart it
}

private void myTimer_Elapsed(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Explanation: Each time the text changes, the timer gets reset and started again. It will only tick if it's enabled (aka not stopped by the `TextChanged` event) for a second.
If you want it to tick only once and then stop, set the `AutoReset` property to true.

Comment: But how can i get the value of my TextBox in myTimer_Elapsed. It's say to me that an other thread is the owner

Comment: You need to use `Control.Invoke` since the control you're trying to access is on another thread. Have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could **inherit** from TextBox and raise your own `StableTextChanged` event.  The new control will appear at the top of your ToolBox:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBoxEx1_StableTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = ((TextBoxEx)sender).Text;
    }

}

public class TextBoxEx : TextBox
{

    public event dlgStableTextChanged StableTextChanged;
    public delegate void dlgStableTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e);

    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr;

    public TextBoxEx()
    {
        tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        tmr.Interval = 1000;
        tmr.Tick += Tmr_Tick;
        this.TextChanged += TextBoxEx_TextChanged;
    }

    private void Tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmr.Stop();
        if (this.StableTextChanged != null)
        {
            this.StableTextChanged(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    private void TextBoxEx_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmr.Stop();
        tmr.Start();
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't use forms I use Page

Comment: Ah...you're using **WPF**.  Please include that information in your tags and/or description next time.

Comment: Ok sorry, Thanks for your help anyway